# Verificar se os elementos da pilha 1 são iguais os elementos da pilha 2, C++

Tags: c++, stack

Galera, Boa noite!! Preciso fazer essa parte do código em C++ comparando se os elementos da Pilha 1 são os mesmos da Pilha 2 e se a quantidade de elementos são exatamente iguais. Não sei implementar essa parte do código.
Criei a variável int i para percorrer a lista. #MeAjudem

```
int compara_pilha1_com_pilha2 (Pilha* pi1, Pilha* pi2)
{
   int i;

   if(pi1 == NULL || pi1->qtd == 0 || pi2 == NULL || pi2->qtd == 0)
   {
    return 0;
   }
   for(i = 0; i<pi1->qtd; i++)
   {

   }
```

Comment: Como está definida a estrutura `Pilha` ? Como foram inseridos os elementos ?

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo as modificações necessárias em cx11++

Essas modificações deve lhe ajudar:

```
int compara_pilha1_com_pilha2 (Pilha* pi1, Pilha* pi2)
{
   //verifica se não esta nulo
   if(pi1 == nullptr || pi2 == nullptr)
   {
     return 0;
   }
   //verifica se as duas pilas não estão com quantidade igual a 0 e se 
   //as quantidades são iguais
   if(pi1->qtd == 0 || pi2->qtd == 0 || pi1->qtd != pi2->qtd)
   {
     return 0;
   }
   //para comparar agora falta os campos
   //vamos supor que seja value
   for(auto i = 0; i < pi1->qtd; i++)
   {
      if((pi1 + i)->value != (pi2 + i)->value)
      {
        return 1;
      }
   } 
   return 0;
}
```